# convert PostGIS point object to geoJSON for mapping

Tags: javascript, json, django, postgis, geojson

I have a Django app with a postgres db of PostGIS activities I'm trying to map on a frontend view using leaflet and Mapbox.

I'm serializing the activities in the view and rendering them in the template as geoJSON (`{{ props.activitiesJson|safe }}`)

[can render this as html and see the JSON objects on the page].

views.py (ex)

```
def map(request):

    mapbox_key = settings.MAPBOX_API_KEY
    activities = Activity.get_activities_near(lat, lng, radius)

    props = {'activitiesJson' : serializers.serialize('geojson', activities),}

    context = {
    'props' : props,
    'mapbox_key': mapbox_key
}

return render(request, 'app/map.html', context)
```

template:

```
var map_activities = JSON.parse("{{ props.activitiesJson }}");
L.geoJSON(map_activities).addTo(map);
```

if I render `{{ props.activitiesJson }}` or `{{ props.activitiesJson|safe }}` directly on the template (not inside a script or parsing it) I see this data structure:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"cause": 1, "name": "Test Action", "slug": "test-action", "is_active": true, "image": "test.jpeg", "description": "test description", "date_start": null, "date_end": null, "skills_required": false, "on_site": false, "address_street": "123 Main St.", "address_street_2": "", "address_city": "New York", "address_state": "NY", "address_zip": "10013", "address_country": "", "location_city": "", "location_state": "", "location_country": "", "skills_list": [], "pk": "1"}, "geometry": null}]}
```

but trying to parse it with JSON.parse() throws a syntax err:

```
JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

how do I validly assign that geoJSON object to my map_activities var? do I need to parse it at all? (i.e., `var map_activities = {{ props.activitiesJson|safe }};`)

thanks

Comment: Could you paste how the rendered json in `JSON.parse("{{ props.activitiesJson|safe }}");` looks like?

Comment: @KamilNiski added direct render of {{ props.activitiesJson|safe }} - I can't console.log or render the JSON.parse() because of "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ultimately (not sure if this is best practice) the right approach for me was not parsing the geoJSON object at all and passing it straight to the variable

```
var map_activities = {{ props.activitiesJson|safe }};
```

Comment: If your activities contain any user-supplied input, this approach is an XSS security vulnerability! Set one of your activity names to `</script><script>alert('XSS')</script>` and see what happens. You must use the `escapejs` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can try below code.

```
def map(request):    
   activities = Activity.get_activities_near(lat, lng, radius)
   activitiesData = []
   for activity in activities:
      listdata = {'id': activity.id, 'name': activity.name} # As per requirement
      activitiesData.append(listdata)
   response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(activitiesData))
   return response
```